# SwitchMasterToWeb.config in Sitecore 8.1 Update 2 missing patch for sitecore_list_index

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Last week I upgraded from Sitecore 8.0 Update 5 to Sitecore 8.1 Update 2.

I ran into one issue where the *SwitchMasterToWeb.config* example included with Sitecore 8.1 Update 2 does not seem to include a patch to delete *sitecore_list_index*.   This patch does exist in Sitecore 8.1 initial release???

Without the patch, this error is thrown (https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/347205)     Manually adding the patch removes this error.   Was the removal of the patch an error on the part of Sitecore?   Or is there something I need to do to avoid this error from being thrown?

I also note there does not appear to be a patch to remove: *sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master*     I would think that should also be removed with *SwitchMasterToWeb.config*.   Is there a reason that reference to a master index was not patched?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Question is why am I getting the error with the example file that is included in 8.1 Update 2 (or why was the patch removed from the file since it seems to be needed?)  Or is something else missing?

Comment: I would try asking this one on https://community.sitecore.net you'll be able to get Sitecore to confirm the exact settings you'll need patched.

Comment: You should also try raising a Sitecore support ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Jay that SwitchMasterToWeb.config has never been implemented without noticing a few issues.

The reason you get that error is because there is no 'syncMaster' index update strategy is usually deleted along with all 'master' database indexes. That may have been deleted in the SwitchMastertoWeb.config file as well. Check to see if this exists in the file -

```
<indexUpdateStrategies>
   <syncMaster>
      <patch:delete />
   </syncMaster>
</indexUpdateStrategies>
```

Deleting 'sitecore_list_index' may also cause you some issues. The issues caused by deleting 'sitecore_list_index' maybe the reason that Sitecore left it out of SwitchMasterToWeb.config file. Here is an issue caused by deleting 'sitecore_list_index' - http://sitecoreunleashed.blogspot.com/2015/07/sitecore-8-update-3-cd-servers-and.html.

To get around the issues above, we set the index update strategy of 'sitecore_list_index' to 'onPublishEndAsync' instead of deleting it.

```
<index id="sitecore_list_index">
   <strategies>
      <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" patch:instead="strategy[@ref='contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster']"/>
   </strategies>
   <locations>
      <crawler>
         <Database>web</Database>
      </crawler>
   </locations>
</index>
```

You can even try to set the indexUpdateStrategy to 'manual' instead of onPublishEndAsync and check the logs for issues. Manual strategy only builds an index when you tell it to via code or from the Sitecore interface.

To read more about Index Update Strategies, try this link - https://dev.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/index_update_strategies

Answer (score 2):

To this day, I have never been able to launch a site (without errors) using the out of the box SwitchMasterToWeb. It always seems to miss something that was newly introduced, or is in a subfolder that patches in after, or some other reason.

You have most likely identified a bug in the SwitchMasterToWeb file for 8.1 Update 2 and should log a ticket with Sitecore identifying the issue. In the meantime, you'll need to deploy your own patches to resolve the issue. If you provide this to Sitecore in your ticket, they could then use that for future fixes to the SwitchMasterToWeb.

It is also possible that Support has already received this issue from another client and may have a patched SwitchMasterToWeb to provide you for your usage.